# What do creating an object "explicitly" and "implicitly as a result of elaboration" mean?

Tags: programming-languages, computer-science

From [p498 of Programming Language Pragmatics, by Scott](https://books.google.com/books?id=jM-cBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA495&ots=ysB5f5Syj4&pg=PA496#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> **With a reference model for variables**, every object is **created
>   explicitly**, and it is easy to ensure that an appropriate constructor
>   is called.
>
> **With a value model for variables**, object creation can happen
>   **implicitly as a result of elaboration**.  In Ada, which doesn’t provide
>   automatic calls to constructors by default, elaborated objects begin
>   life uninitialized, and it is possible to accidentally attempt to use
>   a variable before it has a value. In C++, the compiler ensures that an
>   appropriate constructor is called for every elaborated object, but the
>   rules it uses to identify constructors and their arguments can
>   sometimes be confusing.

What does it mean by creating an object "explicitly" and "implicitly as a result of elaboration"?

What does "elaboration" mean?

Thanks.